# Using LINQ to Group By List<string> Values

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following SortedDictionary:

```
SortedDictionary<string, List<string>> dict 
            = (SortedDictionary<string,List<string>>) MyObj.GetDict();
```

There are many lists with the same values in dict, and I want to use LINQ to collapse all these rows with similar lists into one row. However, each list is an object, so LINQ sees them all as distinct entities.

My question is: how can I set up my code so that a GroupBy(grp => grp.Value) actually groups the dictionary by the contents of the list, and not the list object itself?

Comment: Does the order or the case of the strings in the list matter?

Comment: Order matters. There are never duplicates in the lists.

Comment: if `dict = {"first", {"11", "12", "13"}}, {"second", {"11", "12", "13"}}, {"third", {"31", "32", "33"}}, {"fourth", {"31", "32", "33", "34"}}}`, what output do you expect? Post some sample input and output.

Comment: Let's say I use your dictionary with the following code:

    dict.GroupBy(row => row.Value).Select(g => new { ID = g.Key, List = g.First().Value })

I would expect to see 

"first"    {"11", "12", "13"}
"third"    {"31", "32", "33"}
"fourth"   {"31", "32", "33", "34"}

Comment: @user2118062 - then what output would you expect? please update the question with the sample input and expected results.

Comment: isn't it little contrived then? the initial list had two keys ("first" and "second"), which now have been merged into single key ("first")? What's the purpose of key then? Do you want `List<string>` as key and `string` as value i.e. Dictionary<List<string>, string>>? Although that also doesn't look right.

Comment: The strings in the lists are read in one at a time from a file. They are associated with an ID, which is the key in this dictionary. Every time I encounter a string in the file, I add it to the list in the dictionary under its key's bucket. Once I have collected all values from the file, I want to eliminate all redundant sequences and only keep those which are unique. It doesn't matter which key I end up with, so long as that key points to a unique list of strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a custom `IEqualityComparer<IList<string>>` which you can use for most linq methods like `GroupBy` or `Distinct`. Note that it works also for `string[]` which implements `IList<string>`:

```
public class IgnoreOrderComparer : IEqualityComparer<IList<string>>
{
    public IgnoreOrderComparer(StringComparer comparer)
    {
        this.Comparer = comparer;
    }

    public StringComparer Comparer { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(IList<string> x, IList<string> y)
    {
        if (x == null || y == null) return false;
        // remove the Distincts if there are never duplicates as mentioned
        return !x.Distinct(Comparer).Except(y.Distinct(Comparer), Comparer).Any();
        // btw, this should work if the order matters:
        // return x.SequenceEqual(y, Comparer);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(IList<string> arr)
    {
        if (arr == null) return int.MinValue;
        int hash = 19;
        foreach (string s in arr.Distinct(Comparer))
        {
            hash = hash + s.GetHashCode();
        }
        return hash;
    }
}
```

Then you can use following queries to create a dictinct `SortedDictionary<string, List<string>>`.

sample data:

```
SortedDictionary<string, List<string>> dict = new SortedDictionary<string, List<string>>();
dict.Add("A", new List<string>() { "A", "B" });
dict.Add("B", new List<string>() { "B", "B" });
dict.Add("C", new List<string>() { "A", "B" });
dict.Add("D", new List<string>() { "C", "E" });
dict.Add("E", new List<string>() { "E", "C" });
```

using `Distinct` on the lists first, then join them with the original dictionary, finally create a new one:

```
var comparer = new IgnoreOrderComparer(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
var uniqueLists = dict.Values.Distinct(comparer);
var uniqueDict = from list in uniqueLists
                 join kvp in dict 
                 on list equals kvp.Value
                 select kvp;
dict = new SortedDictionary<string,List<string>>(uniqueDict.ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value));
```

It might be helpful even if the order of the strings in the lists matters.

Comment: I can't thank you enough! I've been trying to solve this problem for a while now. Thanks!

Comment: How could I implement the comparer so that it checks for order? Just modify the Equals method to check for equal length and then iterate over each element to check that each element is the same at each index?

Comment: @user2118062: Use `SequenceEqual`. e.g.: `return x.SequenceEqual(y, Comparer);`. And change the name of the class ;)